# Reading a BYTE array into a DWORD array

Tags: assembly, masm, irvine32

I am attempting to finish a homework assignment that involves creating a BYTE array of 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 in assembly, swapping those values to an array of type DWORD, displaying the results, swapping the order of the values and displaying again in assembly. I have every piece working EXCEPT swapping from 8->32 bit arrays. Here is my most recent iteration of attempts:

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
byteArray BYTE 2, 4, 6, 8, 10
intArray DWORD ?

.code
main PROC
    Swap:
        mov si,OFFSET byteArray     ;si=byteArray
        mov ebx,OFFSET intArray     ;ebx=intArray
        mov ecx,LENGTHOF byteArray  ;since byteArray is the one defined ATM

        swaploop:
            mov eax,[si]
            mov [ebx], eax  
            inc esi
            add ebx, 4
            loop swaploop
```

Comment: Why `si` instead of `esi`?

Comment: I had initially tried using ebx and the compiler was giving me an error about index arrays?

Answer (score 3):

A DWORD is 32 bits right?  A number in your BYTE array is 8 bits right?  So, your intArray at most can hold 4 numbers but not in the way you expect.  Instead, (If I understand you correctly) is to create a DWORD array to hold all 5 numbers:

```
.data
byteArray   BYTE 2, 4, 6, 8, 10

.data?
intArray    DWORD lengthof byteArray dup (?)
```

This:

```
intArray DWORD ?
```

might seem like it holds all your numbers, but when you move more than one byte to the `intArray` address, it will step on what ever comes after `intArray`

```
    xor     ecx, ecx                ; index into arrays, 0 on start
    mov     esi, offset byteArray   ; address of byteArray
    mov     edi, offset intArray    ; address of intArray

MoveEm:
    movzx   eax, byte ptr [esi + ecx]   ; move byte from (address) byteArray + ecx into eax, zero extending eax
    mov     dword ptr [edi + 4 * ecx], eax  ; move byte in eax, into (address) intArray + 4 * ecx
    inc     ecx
    cmp     ecx, lengthof byteArray
    jne     MoveEm
```

Comment: Awesome, the assignment had specified to do things in a certain way. However, your response helped me to get it working, so many thanks.